# WSREP: Failed to read 'ready ' from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address

Tags: mariadb, galera

When I attempt to join a node to a cluster using the xtrabackup sst option, I get the following error:

> WSREP: Failed to read 'ready ' from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address...

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run `wsrep_sst_xtrabackup` manually, which reported

```
Can't find nc in the path
```

Running

```
yum install nc
```

fixed the issue.